# Отправка данных формы POST Java EE

Tags: java, post, form

Есть форма данных пользователя. Есть фильтр который обрабатывает форму, и если есть POST данные проверяет и сохраняет. Проблема в том что если я один раз нажму на сохранить (тогда делаетсяsubmit формы на той же странице и при этом фильтр отрабатывает) и потом просто обновляю страницу то POST данные всё равно есть. Как их убрать или что-то сделать с ними?

Answer (score 1):

Реализуйте подход Post/Redirect/Get, когда после обработки Post запроса выполняется редирект на ту страницу, с которой выполнялась отправка формы. Это обеспечит то, что повторное обновление страницы (например, при нажатии F5) не будет приводить к повторной отправке данных формы.
Подробнее можете прочитать, например, тут: http://javastudy.ru/patterns/pattern-prg-postredirectget-in-java/